# How to achieve the Great Administrator award?

Tags: paradise-island

How to achieve the Great Administrator award?

What are the conditions for that award?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out wikia.com and got this from under the game Paradise Island.

**Great Administrator**

Improve Administrative Building at least to level 50.

The rewards are 3000 XP and 15€.

You can visit the link here : http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Awards